# Extracting latitude and longitude from email with regular expressions php

Tags: php, regex, email

i am a newbie when it comes to regular expressions, i need to make a script that will search the body of an email and extract floats that will be in this format (0.000000,0.000000), although they could also be negative or be higher than 10 like: (32.000000, -1.000000)

```
$body = utf8_decode(imap_qprint(imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number, 2.1)));
```

The $body variable will contain something similar to

```
text text text text text text Coordinates: (0.000000, -0.000000) text text
```

Comment: Whatever i found here on SO and other sources but nothing seems to work

Comment: have you checked [regexlib](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=float) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
preg_match('#(-?\d+\.\d+), *(-?\d+\.\d+)#', $body, $coordinates);
```

You'll find them in $coordinates[1] and $coordinates[2].